# change catcode with tickets (business card print) and tables

Tags: typewriter, catcodes, longtabu, cards

### Update, much later

Don’t do this. Change the font instead. This just causes much trouble in unexpected and hard-to-debug places. See [the other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230183/43807) to the same question for details.

### changing the direction of the slash of the digit zero

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230214/43807) I learned how to change the direction of the slash through the digit `0` inside a `texttt` block. This works fine, except it doesn’t work in a ticket environment.

Note we use pdflatex (run twice).

### business cards

[SSCCE](https://www.mirbsd.org/wtf.cgi?q=SSCCE):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[zw32010,boxed]{ticket}% for debugging
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphics}
\RequirePackage{ngerman}
\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{pxfonts}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newcommand\0{\scalebox{-1}[1]{0}}
\let\svttfamily\ttfamily
\let\svtexttt\texttt
\catcode`0=\active
\def0{\0}
\renewcommand\ttfamily{\svttfamily\catcode`0=\active }
\renewcommand\texttt{\bgroup\ttfamily\texttthelp}
\def\texttthelp#1{#1\egroup}
\catcode`0=12

\renewcommand{\ticketdefault}{
    \put(1,46){\LARGE SSCCE}
    \put(2,38){texttt:}
    \put(2,32){implicit:}
    \put(2,26){explicit:}
}

\newcommand{\vcard}[1]{\ticket{
    \put(30,38){\texttt{#1}}
    \put(30,32){\ttfamily #1}
    \put(30,26){\ttfamily\catcode`0=\active #1}
}}

\begin{document}

\vcard{x0y}

\vspace{10cm}

Outside, \texttt{a0b} with texttt.

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the slash through the `0` is from bottom-left to top-right outside, but I can’t seem to get it working for inside the business card. I thought this was because of `\put` at first, but placing the text of the `\ticketdefault` or `\ticket` in there “raw”, i.e. not inside a `\put`, doesn’t fix it either:

```
\newcommand{\vcard}[1]{\ticket{

        Outside \texttt{m0n} with texttt.

        \put(30,38){\texttt{#1}}
        \put(30,32){\ttfamily #1}
        \put(30,26){\ttfamily\catcode`0=\active #1}
}}
```

(same for `\ticketdefault`)

### tables

```
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphics}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{pxfonts}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\RequirePackage{hyphenat}

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcommand\0{\scalebox{-1}[1]{0}}
\let\svttfamily\ttfamily
\let\svtexttt\texttt
\catcode`0=\active
\def0{\0}
\renewcommand\ttfamily{\svttfamily\catcode`0=\active }
\renewcommand\texttt{\bgroup\ttfamily\texttthelp}
\def\texttthelp#1{#1\egroup}
\catcode`0=12

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

Das kann doch nicht sein! foo0bar \texttt{baz0blah} meh!

 \begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {|@{}c@{}|X|X|l|l|l|l|}
\hline\rowfont\bfseries Foto & Nachname & Vorname & Geburts\-datum & Benutzer & Fahrt & Fahr\-karte \\\hline
\endhead
x & \nohyphens{Lastname} & \nohyphens{Firstname} & \nohyphens{1970-01-01} & \texttt{hal2001} & \nohyphens{nein} & \nohyphens{nein}\\\hline
 \end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

As can be seen, this also does not work in tables ☹

Answer (score 1):

You have to activate `0` before absorbing the argument; I also present a fixed version of the reversed slashed zero macros.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[zw32010,boxed]{ticket}% for debugging
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{pxfonts}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\LetLtxMacro\svttfamily\ttfamily
\begingroup\ttfamily\endgroup
\DeclareRobustCommand\ttfamily{%
  \catcode`0=\active
  \svttfamily
}
\LetLtxMacro{\svtexttt}{\texttt}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\texttt}{\begingroup\catcode`0=\active\dotexttt}
\newcommand\dotexttt[1]{\svtexttt{#1}\endgroup}

\newcommand\0{\scalebox{-1}[1]{0}}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`0 \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\0}

\renewcommand{\ticketdefault}{%
  \put(1,46){\LARGE SSCCE}%
  \put(2,38){texttt:}%
  \put(2,32){implicit:}%
  \put(2,26){explicit:}%
}

\newcommand{\vcard}{\begingroup\catcode`0=\active\dovcard}
\newcommand{\dovcard}[1]{%
  \ticket{%
    \put(30,38){\texttt{#1}}%
    \put(30,32){\ttfamily#1}%
    \put(30,26){\ttfamily#1}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

Outside, \texttt{a0b} with texttt. 

\vcard{x0y}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different implementation with `expl3` that doesn't require a helper command for `\vcard`, avoiding a group.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[zw32010,boxed]{ticket}% for debugging
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{letltxmacro,xparse}
\usepackage{pxfonts}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newcommand\0{\scalebox{-1}[1]{0}}

% save the meaning of \ttfamily
\LetLtxMacro\svttfamily\ttfamily
% load the .fd file before changing the meaning of \ttfamily
\begingroup\ttfamily\endgroup

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\ttfamily}{}
 {
  \char_set_catcode_active:N 0
  \svttfamily
 }
\RenewDocumentCommand{\texttt}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \ttfamily
  \tl_rescan:nn { } { #1 }
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begingroup\lccode`~=`0 \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\0}

\renewcommand{\ticketdefault}{%
  \put(1,46){\LARGE SSCCE}%
  \put(2,38){texttt:}%
  \put(2,32){implicit:}%
  \put(2,26){explicit:}%
}

\newcommand{\vcard}[1]{%
  \ticket{%
    \put(30,38){\texttt{#1}}%
    \put(30,32){\ttfamily#1}%
    \put(30,26){\ttfamily#1}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

Outside, \texttt{a0b} with texttt.

Outside, {\ttfamily a0b} with ttfamily.

\vcard{x0y}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @mirabilos I hope it is good now.

Comment: What does `\begingroup\lccode`~=`0 \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\0}` do?

Comment: @mirabilos It defines the active version of `0`, avoiding resetting the category code. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156759/the-lowercase-trick

Comment: OK, thanks. I do not even pretend to understand that, less than the previous version, even if I can see a few things… so, on to tables: any idea wrt. them? This works for normal text, lstlistings, and business cards now, so far.

Comment: @mirabilos My choice would be forgetting a font that doesn't satisfy your needs. There are *many* things that can go wrong with an active `0`; for example, `{\ttfamily\setlength{\mylength}{10pt}...}` will break horribly.

Comment: OK, thanks, we’ll reconsider that decision then. Back then, a minimal-intrusive change was better; by now, we’ll want extensive layout changes (geometry package was understood now, and I wish to convert all pages to fancyhdr) which require reviewing all old documents anyway, so we can do that. – Nevertheless, thanks a lot for your help!